# AngularJS: How do I watch a form for changes, but throttle the rate of JSON requests?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, angularjs, rest

I have a search form, and I'd like to automatically update the results every time one of the fields changes. I'd like to throttle the rate of JSON requests to the server. How do I go about this?

**Example**

```
[Name] [Age] [Subjects]
=======================
// Results automatically updated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-model-options to delay the to call the search, like this

```
ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0}}"
```

Add this to every textbox

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.name"
             ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0}}">
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="student.age"
            ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0}}">
Subject: <input type="text" ng-model="student.subject"
            ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0}}">
```

It will not update the value until 1 second or you left the control.

```
$scope.$watch('student', function(newval, oldval) {
   if(newval != oldval){
      //call the search method
   }
}, true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have a search system that allows you to search for

```
<h1>Student Search</h1>
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="student.name">
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="student.age">
Subject: <input type="text" ng-model="student.subject">
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('student', function() {

    $timeout.cancel($scope.delayedRequest);

    $scope.delayedRequest = $timeout(function() {
        // REST Request in here!
    }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: So you posted question and then start searching and now providing the answer, great